# LeetCode 83. Remove Duplicates from Sorted List

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, null-pointer

I don't know why the result of subit is "member access within null pointer of type 'struct ListNode'". I tested the sample and the capital was correct, I don't know what is wrong with my cognition of the empty indicators, can someone help me?

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */


struct ListNode* deleteDuplicates(struct ListNode* head){
   
    struct ListNode* node = head;
    while(node->next != NULL && node != NULL){
        if(node->val == node->next->val){
            struct ListNode* duplicate = node->next;
            node->next = node->next->next;
            free(duplicate);
        }
        else node = node->next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is empty `head` will be `NULL`.  In the `while` loop expression `node` is dereferenced using `node->next` which is evaluated before the right hand side, which checks `node` for `NULL`.  You should check to see if `node` is `NULL` before evaluating the `while` loop and `NULL` checks for `node` should always be performed before `NULL` checks for `node->next`.

This would be my suggestion:

```
struct ListNode* deleteDuplicates(struct ListNode* head){
   
    struct ListNode* node = head;
    while(node != NULL){
        if(node->next == NULL)
        {
           node = node->next;
        }
        else if(node->val == node->next->val){
            struct ListNode* duplicate = node->next;
            node->next = node->next->next;
            free(duplicate);
        }
        else node = node->next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!I’m very grateful for your help!